# Volvo - send commands to read DTCs

Tags: obd-ii, volvo, torque, can-bus, scan-tool

I tried finding out the commands a diagnostic tool sends to my Volvo and I got this -

1D D0 16 16 03 22 F1 86
Protocol - CAN 29/500 (elm command: AT SP 7)

Can someone help me with the method to send the commands in Torque app? (like set a header, PID, formula etc)?

Comment: So, what did the info you received mean?

Comment: @SolarMike it's command for reading ECU ID